# How to send notification from WCF service to android using firebase?

Tags: c#, php, android, wcf

I have create a WCF service to send notification to my android application but 
its not working.

```
public string SendNotification1( string senderId, string deviceId, string message)
{
     string serverApiKey, serverApiKey = "*myserverkey";  

     string result;

     var value = message;

     WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
     tRequest.Method = "post";
     tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
     tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverApiKey));
     tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));

     string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
                + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";

     Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

     using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
     {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                {
                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
        }
     }


     return message;
}
```

My service1:

```
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "SendNotification?senderId={senderId}&deviceId={deviceId}&message={message}")]
   string SendNotification1(string senderId, string deviceId, string message);
```

When my Android application start I use service to save device token.

I send success full notification using PHP but I need it with WCF service the PHP code is:

```
<?php 

function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array(

         'registration_ids' => $tokens,

         'data' => $message

        );

        $headers = array(

        'Authorization:key =mykeyyyyyyy',

        'Content-Type: application/json'

        );

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   if ($result === FALSE) {

       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));

   }

   curl_close($ch);

   return $result;

} 

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fcm2");

$sql = " Select Token From users";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$tokens = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn); 
$message = array("message" => "my message");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status ;
?>
```

`$`